# iText7 indented list formatting with Java

Tags: java, itext, nested-lists, itext7

I am using iText 7 to create a list. I need to have multiple levels of indentations.

Example:

- Item 1

  - Sub Item 1
  - Sub Item 2

    - Sub Sub Item 1
    - Sub Sub Item 2
- Item 2

  - Sub Item 1
  - Sub Item 2

    - Sub Sub Item 1
    - Sub Sub Item 2    - Sub Item 1
  - Sub Item 2

    - Sub Sub Item 1
    - Sub Sub Item 2
- Item 3

  - Sub Item 1
  - Sub Item 2

    - Sub Sub Item 1
    - Sub Sub Item 2

Current Attempt:

```
public void IndentedList() throws IOException {
    String filePath = dest + "Example2.pdf";
    File file = new File(filePath);
    file.getParentFile().mkdirs();

    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(filePath);
    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);

    Document document = new Document(pdf);

    PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontConstants.TIMES_ROMAN);

    document.add(new Paragraph("iText is: ").setFont(font));

    List list = new List()
            .setSymbolIndent(12)
            .setListSymbol("\u2022")
            .setFont(font);
    
    list
            .add(new ListItem("Item 1"))
            .add(new ListItem("SubItem1"))
            .add(new ListItem("Sub Sub Item 1"))
            .add(new ListItem("Sub Sub Item 2"));
            .add(new ListItem("Item 1"))
            .add(new ListItem("SubItem1"))
            .add(new ListItem("Sub Sub Item 1"))
            .add(new ListItem("Sub Sub Item 2"));
    document.add(list);
    document.close();
}
```

How can I indent the specific list items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please take a look at the documentation, more specifically [Chapter 4](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-4-adding-abstractelement-objects-part-1) of the [iText 7: Building Blocks](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/) tutorial.

Currently you are not nesting lists. You add each list item to the top level list. You need to nest lists, see for instance:

```
public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException {
    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
    Document document = new Document(pdf);
    List topLevel = new List();
    ListItem item1 = new ListItem();
    item1.add(new Paragraph().add("Item 1"));
        List secondLevel = new List();
        secondLevel.add("Sub Item 1");
        ListItem subItem2 = new ListItem();
        subItem2.add(new Paragraph("Sub Item 2"));
            List thirdLevel = new List();
            thirdLevel.add("Sub Sub Item 1");
            thirdLevel.add("Sub Sub Item 2");
        subItem2.add(thirdLevel);
        secondLevel.add(subItem2);
    item1.add(secondLevel);
    topLevel.add(item1);
    document.add(topLevel);
    document.close();
}
```

The resulting PDF looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the sub lists are indented because you add a `List` object to a `ListItem`. This is true nesting. In your code, you don't introduce that hierarchy which is why you're not getting the desired result.